# `Get into a flap` - is it correct?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

I've found a lot of examples of expression "Get in a flap" but in my coursebook the expression is said with "into" instead of "in". Are those prepositions interchangeable or is that an error in the book?

Comment: The prepositions aren't *always* interchangeable, but as the accepted answer notes, they are similar and thus often *can* be interchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions are interchangeable, and ngrams suggests that both forms are about equally common (in the books that Google has scanned)

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+in+a+flap%2C+get+into+a+flap&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20in%20a%20flap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20into%20a%20flap%3B%2Cc0)

In general, saying "He got into the box" and "He got in the box" have the same or very similar meanings.  But when used without an explict noun, only "in" is used.

> Hitchhiker: I want a ride to London
>   Driver: Sure. Get in.